# Obtengo el error "TypeError: producto() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cantidad'"

Tags: python

No sé porque obtengo ese error, cuando tengo puesto todos los parámetros bien, es sobre una base de datos en `.csv` hecha en Python

```
class Cliente(Empresa):
    def __init__(self,Nombre, Celular, Edad, Cedula):
        self.nombre_de_la_empresa = Nombre
        self.Numero_de_celular = Celular
        self.Nombre = Nombre
        self.Edad = Edad
        self.Celular = Celular
        self.Cedula= Cedula

    def mostrar(self):
        msg = "Nombre de la empresa: "+ self.nombre_de_la_empresa + "\nNumero de Celular: " + str(self.Numero_de_celular) + "\nNombre: " + self.Nombre + "\nEdad: " + str(self.Edad) + "\nNumero De Celular: " + str(self.Celular) + "\nCedula: "+ str(self.Cedula)
        return msg


    def producto(self, codigo, precio, cantidad):

        self.Codigo = codigo
        self.Precio = precio
        self.Cantidad = cantidad
```

Comment: Puedes añadir la parte donde estás llamando al método?

Comment: He respondido a lo que te está ocurriendo, Si no encuentras el error, por favor edita la pregunta añadiendo todo el código así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error lo que te quiere decir es que has invocado al método `producto` de tu clase cliente, **pero en vez de pasarle los tres parámetros** que tiene el método (código, precio, cantidad) **le has pasado solo 2**, por lo que te faltaría pasarle un parámetro más para poder llamar al método de la clase correctamente.